# Can't receive UDP broadcast in python

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, broadcast

Here is broadcast server

```
from time import sleep
from socket import *

PORT = 50000
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 0))
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)

data = "I am server"
while 1:
    s.sendto(data, ('<broadcast>', PORT))
    print "sent data"
    sleep(5)
```

Please note that you need to change `'<broadcast>'` with actual broadcast address of your network.  Please see [Python can't send a broadcast package with  address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995425/python-cant-send-a-broadcast-package-with-broadcast-address)

Here is broadcast receiver

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
PORT = 50000
client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
client.bind(('0.0.0.0', PORT))
data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024) #sticks here forever!

if data:
    print "Found Broadcast server at : " + addr
```

But problem is that my receiver just sticks at `s.recvfrom(1024)`
While through tcpdump I am able to see the packet, then why this python client is not able to catch it ?
command is `sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 ip -X dst host 255.255.255.255`

Answer (score -1):

I changed your code to Python 3 and corrected 2 errors:

- Change `s` to `client`
- Print the statement only when there is data from `recvfrom()`

Hope it helps.

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
PORT = 50000
client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
client.bind(('0.0.0.0', PORT))

while True:
  data, addr = client.recvfrom(1024) #sticks here forever!
  if data:
    print("Found Broadcast server at : ", addr)
```

Answer (score -5):

You need to set socket options before you bind it, and you need to bind it to INADDR_BROADCAST.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, I will not write the code for you. I believe, my suggestions are clear.

Comment: Tell at least what options do I need to set up to the socket, and for server I've already set up socket options

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, the same - SO_BROADCAST.

Comment: I don't think the suggestion is clear, and in fact, the suggested approach for IPv4 (python2 socket) seems to be to use '<broadcast>' as a host name, though this doesn't appear to rectify the problem either. https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

Comment: NB: what seems to be implied (by this answer above) actually fails - 'an invalid parameter was supplied'. Should have mentioned that in previous comment. So to explain downvote: solution isn't clear, and what seems suggested doesn't work.